# Primefaces datatable row edit is not working opposite to what is shown in official site

Tags: primefaces, jsf-2, datatable

Primefaces :6.1
JSF: javax.faces-api-2.2
primefaces-mobile-0.9.4

I have following xhtml file for datatable with row edit. Just copied from official site with minimal changes. But i do not get row edit feature instead I am getting column edit feature. I tried downgrading the version of Primefaces jar to 5.0 just to check but that also did not work either.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui"
xmlns:pt="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/passthrough"
xmlns:pm="http://primefaces.org/mobile">

<f:view renderKitId="PRIMEFACES_MOBILE" />

<h:head>

</h:head>
<body>
<h:form id="form">
<p:growl id="msgs" showDetail="true"/>

<p:dataTable id="cars1" var="document" value="#{dataGridView.setProducts}" editable="true" style="margin-bottom:20px">
    <f:facet name="header">
        Row Editing
    </f:facet>

    <p:ajax event="rowEdit" listener="#{ttEditView.onRowEdit}" update=":form:msgs" />
    <p:ajax event="rowEditCancel" listener="#{ttEditView.onRowCancel}" update=":form:msgs" />

    <p:column headerText="Size">
        <p:cellEditor>
            <f:facet name="output"><h:outputText value="#{document.productSize}" /></f:facet>
            <f:facet name="input"><p:inputText value="#{document.productSize}" style="width:80%"/></f:facet>
        </p:cellEditor>
    </p:column>
    <p:column headerText="Type">
        <p:cellEditor>
            <f:facet name="output"><h:outputText value="#{document.productCategory}" /></f:facet>
            <f:facet name="input"><p:inputText value="#{document.productCategory}" style="width:80%"/></f:facet>
        </p:cellEditor>
    </p:column>
    <p:column style="width:32px">
        <p:rowEditor />
    </p:column>
</p:dataTable>
</h:form>
</body>
</html>
```

I get output something like below.[image]

What i want is from what i see in official site, a row edit feature.

Can some one please tell me what could be wrong ?

Comment: So it works if you **don't** use PrimeFaces mobile 0.9.4? And please always explicitly state your jsf version and implementation. The 'api' version does not tell much

Comment: NO, removing PrimeFaces mobile did not solve the problem , Also I thought jsf-api will tell the JSF version. Is not that so ? If api can't tell then what will tell the version of JSF?

Comment: Yes it will tell the JSF API version, but real implementations (there are two different ones) each have their releases and bugfixes... So consult your server (when you use JSF from a server like JBoss, Glassfish or ...) or your project config if using a plain servlet engine (like e.g. Tomcat or ...)  (maven e.g.)

Comment: Oh and did you carefully look at the PrimeFaces showcase for an editable datatable? One of your 'minor' changes has **BIG** impact... hint: `<f:view renderKitId="PRIMEFACES_MOBILE" />`

Comment: YES!! removing `<f:view renderKitId="PRIMEFACES_MOBILE" />` did solve it. BTW I am using JBoss Wildfly. Thanks

Comment: If i have to make this application mobile compatible , is there any alternative ?

Answer (score 1):

By adding

```
<f:view renderKitId="PRIMEFACES_MOBILE" />
```

You force the mobile components to be used. The mobile components do not support all features of the normal components. This is one of them. (You can compare the showcases and check the differences)

PrimeFaces will deprecate the mobile components in 6.2 and will remove them in 6.3. At the same time they will focus on making the normal components behave better on mobile devices. The datatable e.g. has lots of responsiveness features as can be seen in the showcase.

Other responsiveness things should be realized with grid-css and your own media-queries in css. A good quick start are the PrimeFaces elite themes.

If you think something is missing or bugged in a component regarding responsiveness/mobile devices, please file issues in github. They are very keen on acting on them

Answer (score 0):

In JSF, you need to use `<h:body>` instead of `<body>`, otherwise your components won't be rendered correctly.

Comment: No, not specifically neccesary, only if you have tags that need to add something specific to the `h:body` e.g. components which have a 'target="body"' (outputStyleSheet amongst others, but only if the target attribute is used)